# How to set color levels (or white point level) on all layers of an image using gimp?

Tags: white-balance, gimp

I have an image with multiple layers, and I have to set the same white point on all pf them. how can I do it without selecting each layer at once?

Answer (score 1):

Doing the layers one by one, most tools in Gimp can save their settings. You can save them explicitly by giving them names,  but they are also saved automatically (see the `Presets` selector at the top of the Curves or Levels tools).

[image]

So you would just do one layer and then reuse the settings on the others.

Another method is to load them as tiles and make one single big layer, make the change on that layer, and then split it again to tiles (but I don't know a script that does that directly, there are however scripts that can do this after saving the tiles to individual files).

Answer (score 0):

The menu bar has commands to repeat the most recent filter operation, `Filters` -> `Repeat "<previous filter>"`.  It has the shortcut `Ctrl+F`, so you can easily repeat it after selecting each layer.

[image: GIMP menu bar showing recently used filters]

`Colors` -> `Levels...` will also show up in `Filters` -> `Repeat "<previous filter>"` after you use it, even though it lives under the `Colors` menu.